# Using Excel linked to Oracle for Read/Write access

Tags: oracle, excel, automation, conditional-statements, sql-loader

I am wondering if this is possible.

Basically I have a set of 9 users. There is one admin at the top with 2 users under him each with 3 users under them and there is a group of 50 records in an Oracle database table. Each record has a field for read-access and write access.

At the start the admin has all read access and write access. There are 2 sheets in the excel spreadsheet, a read only and a write sheet. Each is populated with the relevant records from the database. The admin should be able to edit the read access and write access fields to a different user name, save the changes, and when that user opens the excel sheet they should only see those records associated with them.

Basically can I automate this? What I want to happen is that when the user opens the excel sheet the excel sheet gets the records associated with them and then they can edit/read as they see fit.

Comment: There's just a single copy of the workbook?  You should be able to automate this by running code when the workbook opens, and hiding all rows not associated with their username.

Comment: I would want each user to have their own copy of the workbook. The workbook would check who you are logged into windows as and pull the records that match your user name. I want the data to be in an Oracle database, not just stored in excel.

Comment: So which part are you having an issue with?

Comment: I'm completely inexperienced with VB so I was just wondering if this is possible to do.

Comment: Ok I've figured out how to load the data now how can I save changes back to Oracle?

Comment: The most usual approach is to use ADO to connect to Oracle then to run update statements to alter the records.